# How do I change toggle id to change "before" css class? Using Unicode

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of FAQ Questions, with some CSS.  What I am wanting to do is change the uni-code before to go from a + to - so from
`content:" \ff0b "; to content:" \002D "`
Here is my code and css and HTML:

```css
.faquestion {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 12px solid rgb(3,59,76);
    border: 2px solid #fff9e6;
    background-color:rgb(3,59,76);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.faquestion:hover{
            color:#000;
            border:2px solid rgb(0,87,152);     
            background-color:#DDCBA4;
        }
.faquestion::before{
    content:" \ff0b ";
    padding-right:8px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function toggler(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).toggle();
}
</script>
<p class="faquestion" onclick="toggler('answer1');"><strong>How do I go to there?</strong></p>
<p class="" id="answer1" style="padding-left: 30px; display: none;">Follow the yellow brick road.</p>

<p class="faquestion" onclick="toggler('answer2');"><strong>What is a virtual experience?</strong></p>
<p class="" id="answer2" style="padding-left: 30px; display: none;">The Virtual experiences is...</p>
```

I feel like I have to add something to toggle code, but not quite sure what to add. Please help!
https://jsfiddle.net/nr3tvaf2/

Comment: Toggling a class that has that rule is probably simplest

Comment: I have "answer1" to "answer20" so are you saying making a class for each one of those?  I am not sure where to get started.

Comment: No make one class something like `.faquestion-clicked::before{ content:"\002D"; }` and then use jquery toggleClass to toggle it on the element that was clicked.

Comment: And perhaps a bit more specific by including the main class in selector...  `.faquestion.faquestion-clicked::before...`

Comment: Is your question still relevant? I can give two solutions.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes, i think so, currently playing with my jsfiddle not quit there yet

Comment: @BeccaAlley, Hello. Did my solution help you? Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Yes, thank you! I have an odd size change happening but I think that is because the minus sign is not as big as the + sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give two solutions.

**The first solution** is to use an `attr()` for the `content: ''` rule, pseudo-class `:before`. Do this in your css:

```
.faquestion::before {
    content: attr(before-content);
    ...
}
```

And add an additional jquery code that allows you to change the icon from **-** to **+** according to the switch principle:

```
$(element).attr("before-content", function (index, attr) {
    return attr == " \uff0b " ? " \u002D " : " \uff0b ";
});
```

Also, initialize the icon to **+** by default:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".faquestion").attr("before-content", " \uff0b ");
});
```

Snippet:

```css
.faquestion {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 12px solid rgb(3, 59, 76);
    border: 2px solid #fff9e6;
    background-color: rgb(3, 59, 76);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.faquestion:hover {
    color: #000;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 87, 152);
    background-color: #ddcba4;
}

.faquestion::before {
    content: attr(before-content);
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".faquestion").attr("before-content", " \uff0b ");
    });
    function toggler(element) {
        $(element).next().toggle();
        $(element).attr("before-content", function (index, attr) {
            return attr == " \uff0b " ? " \u002D " : " \uff0b ";
        });
    }
</script>
<p class="faquestion" onclick="toggler(this);"><strong>How do I go to there?</strong></p>
<p class="" id="answer1" style="padding-left: 30px; display: none;">Follow the yellow brick road.</p>

<p class="faquestion" onclick="toggler(this);"><strong>What is a virtual experience?</strong></p>
<p class="" id="answer2" style="padding-left: 30px; display: none;">The Virtual experiences is...</p>
```

**The second solution** is shorter than the first. The given solution is to use the class.

You need a rule with a **-** sign in your `content: ''`. Add this to your css:

```
.faquestion.minus::before {
    content: " \002D ";
}
```

And add a class switch with the `toggleClass()` method. Like this:

```
$(element).toggleClass("minus");
```

Snippet:

```css
.faquestion {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 12px solid rgb(3, 59, 76);
    border: 2px solid #fff9e6;
    background-color: rgb(3, 59, 76);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.faquestion:hover {
    color: #000;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 87, 152);
    background-color: #ddcba4;
}

.faquestion::before {
    content: " \ff0b ";
    padding-right: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.faquestion.minus::before {
    content: " \002D ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function toggler(element) {
        $(element).next().toggle();
        $(element).toggleClass("minus");
    }
</script>
<p class="faquestion" onclick="toggler(this);"><strong>How do I go to there?</strong></p>
<p class="" id="answer1" style="padding-left: 30px; display: none;">Follow the yellow brick road.</p>

<p class="faquestion" onclick="toggler(this);"><strong>What is a virtual experience?</strong></p>
<p class="" id="answer2" style="padding-left: 30px; display: none;">The Virtual experiences is...</p>
```